# Airbrush-size airless sprayer for painting interior trim?

Tags: painting, trim, interior, spraypainting

I have a lot of detailed interior trim to paint with latex enamel paint. It’s a pain to paint with brushes or small rollers and it seems like it would be so much easier to use a very small airless paint sprayer, like a small airbrush sort of thing. I can’t seem to find something that small though that could be used for this application. Is there such a tool?

Comment: [Spray Can](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Rust-Oleum-Stops-Rust-12-oz-White-Gloss-Protective-Enamel-Spray-Paint-6-Pack-7792830/202058880) ... ?

Comment: Spray cans work pretty well but they make the whole house smell like fumes, and also it's harder to get the exact color I'm using.

Comment: Seems to me that the amount of time to tape and mask off everything to protect it from over spray would be much longer than just using a cutting brush and roller.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch out the tip on an airless to do smaller areas. The first digit is one half the fan size so a 211 has a .011" opening and sprays a 4" fan, that should be acceptable if a spray can works. It does presuppose you rented an airless sprayer. You may also need to change the filter and use a small amount of flow additive. Ask the rental place for advice and what the smallest tip they have is.

If you own an airbrush there's a chance you may be able to run a *detail* HVLP gun off your existing compressor. They require quite a bit less air than full sized guns do, and you might be able to squeak by with a pancake compressor if you're not spraying continuously.